# How can I customize a CSS framework for specific pages in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, frameworks, customization

I'm trying to customize the framework.css for how high or low the sidebar appears on specific pages. Would it be possible to do this using a custom page template and a specific div class declaration? Such as creating a custom template and within that template creating a class to "override" the default css sidebar element settings for those pages? How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make sure the theme is using the function [**`body_class()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) inside the `<body>` tag.

When I select the page template *Sidebar Template* (`wp-content/themes/twenty-eleven/sidebar-page.php`), the class `page-template-sidebar-page-php` shows up in the `body` tag:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to brasofilo's answer, every page has its own class, in case of brasofilo's code, it is the ***page-id-674***. It's generated by wordpress in general.

If you want to do styling on specific pages, you may use something like this:

```
body.page-id-674 div.specific-div-class {
  /*code*/
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: How would I set this up if the div is not in the body, but contained in a div that looks like <aside id="primary" role="complementary"> and has a CSS element class of:                              .sidebars #primary,
.sidebars #secondary,
.content-wide-sidebar #primary {
  width: 250px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: -86px;
 }

Comment: There is `post_class` function, that you can add to `div` or any HTML element.
`<div class=”<?php post_class(); ?>”></div>`
So you can add custom classes like this:

`<div class=”<?php post_class( ‘my-custom-class’ ); ?>”></div>`

This will, in turn, generate a div element that has a variety of class names each of which are added by WordPress and that also include the class you’ve passed as an argument – specifically, `my-custom-class`.